# Records no html samples in Apache JMeter

Tags: html, apache, jmeter, record, sample

i'm trying to use Apache Jmeter.
I followed this tutorial: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

When I start the proxy to record some samples, I get no html-samples in the Recording Controller. If I remove the including URL-Schme '.*\.html' then I get much stuff except html files...

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: same can be done with Exclude other than html. in that case no need to give the include. i.e. include(html)=exclude(other than html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: I had to clear cache and history of the used browser (firefox).

Answer (score 0):

No need to include any URL patterns, just click on add Suggested exclude button and start your recording

Comment: Problem was, even without any URL patterns there was no html file recorded.